# ERROR when using getDate() in sql to filter data

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to set a condition to a field in sp

`If SI0_ADDR.ADDR_EXPR_DATE = '1001-01-01' or > currentDate()`, display address active flag = `'Y'`, else display `'N'`.

I am trying this

```
case [ADDR_EXPR_DATE]
  when '1001-01-01'||[ADDR_EXPR_DATE] > getdate()  then 'Y'
  when  > (getdate()) then 'N'
  else 'N'
end as active_flag
```

Comment: pls ignore the 3rd row in the code

Comment: try cast('1001-01-01' as date)

Comment: I believe my latest edit to my answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This:  `||` is not valid in SQL Server.

EDIT:

Ok read your question again and I think this is what you want:

```
case
      when  [ADDR_EXPR_DATE]='1001-01-01' OR [ADDR_EXPR_DATE] > getdate()  then 'Y'
      else 'N'
    end as active_flag
```

Comment: Thank You for your help. it got executed with this statement

Comment: Please close this question by clicking the checkmark icon to the top left of this answer.